# Is there anyone that can help me with this Runtime error?

Tags: java

I am completely new to programming.I created a program that uses two coordinates entered by the user and calculates the gradient and also comments when the function is increasing or decreasing just like in Mathematics Functions.I get a runtime error whenever i enter a fraction in this format 9/4
.I

```
import java.util.*;
public class mathfunctions {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner coordinates = new Scanner (System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
System.out.println("Enter 2nd y-coordinate:");

Double y2 = coordinates.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter 1st y-coordinate:");
Double y1 = coordinates.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter 2nd x-coordinate:");
Double x2 = coordinates.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter 1st x-coordinate:");

Double x1 = coordinates.nextDouble();
double numerator= (y2-y1);
double denominator= (x2-x1);
double gradient= numerator/denominator;
if
(numerator==0){
 System.out.print("Math Error!!!"); 
}
else{
System.out.print("Gradient=");
System.out.println(gradient);
}
if 
(gradient<0){
  System.out.println("The function is decreasing");    
}
else{
  System.out.println("The function is increasing");
}
  }
/*****************************************
This simple code is used to calculate the slope/gradient also referred to rate of change
*****************************************/
}
```

The error

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:876)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1502)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2433)
    at com.mathfunctions.mathfunctions.main(mathfunctions.java:8)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.duy.android.compiler.java.Java.run(Java.java:115)
    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.executeDex(ExecuteActivity.java:147)
    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.exec(ExecuteActivity.java:124)
    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.access$100(ExecuteActivity.java:45)
    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity$1.run(ExecuteActivity.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: What input did you enter when you ran into this exception?

Comment: `coordinates`? strange name for a `Scanner`.

Comment: i entered 9/4.Meaning 9 divide by 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the exception you are getting is `java.util.InputMismatchException` this is basically telling you that the input by the user doesn't match the expected input, which is what `@SuppaGonzalo` has also noted.

You can easily find the location of the error by looking at the stacktrace which appears below the exception:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:876)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1502)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2433)
at com.mathfunctions.mathfunctions.main(mathfunctions.java:8) <-- THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.duy.android.compiler.java.Java.run(Java.java:115)
at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.executeDex(ExecuteActivity.java:147)
at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.exec(ExecuteActivity.java:124)
at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.access$100(ExecuteActivity.java:45)
at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity$1.run(ExecuteActivity.java:88)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

As you can see in the stacktrace you are calling `nextDouble` on **line 8** of `mathFunctions` class.

```
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2433) <-- THE METHOD WE'RE CALLING.
at com.mathfunctions.mathfunctions.main(mathfunctions.java:8) <-- THE LINE WE ARE CALLING NEXTDOUBLE ON.
```

You have successfully entered `nextDouble` which is fine, but the input the user has entered is **NOT** a Double, so `InputMismatchException` is thrown.

If you look at the code you have provided you have nothing on **line 8**, that is because you haven't shared the whole code, you seem to have missed of the package part; which if you add that in your error is happening this line: `Double y2 = coordinates.nextDouble();`.

From what you have said, you have entered a fraction of **9/4**, this is not a `Double`, so will not get parsed with `nextDouble()`.

What you probably want is something like this to convert your fraction to a `Double`.

```
public static Double convertFractionToDouble(String fraction) throws ParseException {
    if (fraction != null) {
        if (fraction.contains("/")) {
            String[] numbers = fraction.split("/");
            if (numbers.length == 2) {
                BigDecimal numerator = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(numbers[0]));
                BigDecimal denominator = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(numbers[1]));
                BigDecimal response = numerator.divide(denominator, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
                return response.doubleValue();
            }
        } else {
            return Double.valueOf(fraction);
        }
    }
    throw new ParseException(fraction, 0);
}
```

and call it like:

```
Double y2 = convertFractionToDouble(coordinates.next());
```

I would probably add some more validation to the `convertFractionToDouble` method but that is the general idea of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is usually thrown when the user input does not match the expected input. I do not think you are supposed to give a fraction format input. Instead of using (9/4) format input just go with 2.25.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting mismatch input error is your input is not valid in programming, in this case, you have to represent fraction numbers with a point like so:  9/4 => 2.25

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextDouble()` doesn't evaluate expressions: it just reads a literal `double`.